# Jquery autocomplete JSON return result from webservice but it is not showing in dropdownlist

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, asp.net-2.0

I do not know what is wrong with this code. alert shows that data has returned from web service but auto-complete still not showing data. I am using ASP.net 2.0 and google jquery link

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost/WebService/Service.asmx/getlist2",
            dataType: "json",
            data: "{}",


            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function(data) {
         alert("getlist 2");
             alert(data);

                $('#project1').autocomplete({
                    minLength: 2,
                    source: data,

                    focus: function(event, ui) {
                        $('#project1').val(ui.item.TagName);
                        alert(ui.item.TagName);//no alert is fired here
                        return false;
                    },
                    select: function(event, ui) {
                        $('#project1').val(ui.item.TagName);
                        //$('#selectedValue').text("Selected value:" + ui.item.TagID);
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus);
            }
        });
     });
```

and web service method

```
[WebMethod]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public List<Tag> getlist2()
{
    <Tag> tagscollection = new  EntitiesCollection<Tag>();
    ProcessTagList getlisttags = new ProcessTagList();

    string strtag = "";

    Tag tag = new Tag();
    tag.TagName =   strtag;
    tag.UniqueName =   strtag;
    getlisttags.OTag = tag;
    getlisttags.Invoke();
    tagscollection = getlisttags.OTagsCollection;


    ;
      List<Tag> a = new List<Tag>();
    foreach(Tag tagc in tagscollection)
    {
        a.Add(tagc);
    }


    return a;


}
```

data shown in firebug is:

[{"__type":"myproject.Common.Tag","TagID":"21abf6b1-6d45-41e5-a39b-006e621eeb22","UniqueName":"dotnet","TagName":"dotnet","CreatedAt":"/Date(1255108286850)/"}]

this jquery code shows dropdown list from the webservice used with first jquery example.

```
$("#tbAuto").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost/myproject/Service.asmx/getlist2",
            data: "{}",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          //  dataFilter: function(data) { return data; },

            success: function(data) {
                response($.map(data, function(item) {
                    return {
                        value: item.TagName
                    }
                }))
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorTrown);
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 0
});
```

Comment: last example of jquery shows all list of data returned from webservice

Comment: thanks folks I am  little late to response this question. actually i was not returning data according to id, label, value format  side + webservice was inside main project directory. I have placed web service outside the root directory of the project. the reason was Urlrewrite library.

Comment: You should choose an answer as the most correct one by clicking one of the check-signs :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the autocomplete source property to a collection\array. I do not think your returned data is one although it may contain one. You also need to rename your server side object to provide a label value pair. e.g

{ "id": "1", "label": "StackOverflow", "value": "SO" }

Check the examples out [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote) and use firebug to see how they return the json data.

From the docs

> The local data can be a simple Array
>   of Strings, or it contains Objects for
>   each item in the array, with either a
>   label or value property or both. The
>   label property is displayed in the
>   suggestion menu. The value will be
>   inserted into the input element after
>   the user selected something from the
>   menu. If just one property is
>   specified, it will be used for both,
>   eg. if you provide only
>   value-properties, the value will also
>   be used as the label.

Can you paste the json response.

Comment: [{"__type":"myproject.Common.Tag","TagID":"21abf6b1-6d45-41e5-a39b-006e621eeb22","UniqueName":"dotnet","TagName":"dotnet","CreatedAt":"\/Date(1255108286850)\/"},{"__type":"myproject.Common.Tag","TagID":"b6c3adb4-f7b5-4a2c-829c-0bde935a2689","UniqueName":"Foundation,ASP.NET,WCF,","TagName":"Foundation,ASP.NET,WCF,","CreatedAt":"\/Date(1257098846373)\/"}]

Comment: @klusner - youll need to amend your server side object to give the autocomplete a structure that it can work with e.g the one I posted in my answer with label and value properties

Comment: @redsquare  i will show another piece of jquery code that do show dropdownlist but actuall shows all  list rather than  showing specific one that had been typed.check the question edited

Comment: i ve pasted json response here anybody has idea how this code will work.

Comment: thanks folks I am  little late to response this question. actually i was not returing data according to id, label, value format  side + webservice was inside main project directory. I have placed web sevice outside the root directory of the project. the reason was Urlrewrite library.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I know you are using asp.net and my example is based on PHP and MySQL, but since your problem seem to be about the JSON format autocomplete is expecting, I am posting anyway.

Get the latest files from the [jQuery UI page](http://jqueryui.com/download). The autocomplete need UI Core, UI Widget and UI Position from the base package. You also need the autocomplete widget itself.

This example works well for me:

**The HTML:**

```
<div>
    <input id="cities" />
</div>
```

**The script part:**

(It sends the search variable to cities.php as cities.php?term=)

```
$(function() {
  $("#cities").autocomplete({
    source: "backend/cities.php",
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
      // perhaps do something with these?
      region = ui.item.id;
      country = ui.item.label;
      city = ui.item.value;
      secret = ui.item.secret;
   }
});
});
```

**The PHP in cities.php:**

(The variables **id**, **label** and **value** need to be used. Label is used to populate the drop down list. Value is entered into the input box when the label value is clicked in the list).

```
// important to set header with charset
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$term = $_POST["term"];
// some database stuff removed
// loop it through and build array
$n = 0;
    while ($row = $q->fetch()) {
        $row_array[$n]['id'] = $row['City'];
        $row_array[$n]['label'] = $row['Country'];
        $row_array[$n]['value'] = $row['Region'];
        $row_array[$n]['secret'] = 'blabla';
        $n++;
    }
    // encode it to json format
    echo json_encode($row_array);
```

**The JSON sent back:**

(When ?term=new york)

```
[{"id":"New York","label":"United States","value":"New York","secret":"blabla"},{"id":"Minnesota","label":"United States","value":"New York Mills","secret":"blabla"},{"id":"New York","label":"United States","value":"New York Mills","secret":"blabla"}]
```

So, to recap:

- By default, it sends the variable "term" with the search word to the backend page.
- It needs "id", "value" and the "label" variables to be sent back.
- By default the drop down list is populated with the "label"-values.
- By default, clicking in the list will fill out the input box with "value".
- You can put additional variable names and make something with them, but the three above is needed.
- The JSON syntax need to look as provided above.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is not showing up because autocomplete expects the data in a certain way (id,label and value). See other answers as well.

Your getlist2 functions gives another structure of data (__type, TagID,UniqueName,TagName and CreatedAt).

Try to modify getlist2 to give back the proper syntax.

Your last change to the topic start (jquery autocomplete + .ajax) looks alright, what is not working on that piece of code?

Comment: thanks it did solve my problem. I have  created another classs which were specif to the json structure and fill with data.